# How to make MySQL command line works with MAMP?

Tags: mysql, mamp, homebrew

I love the conveniences of MAMP e.g. phpMyAdmin so I installed it.

I also installed MySQL via Home Brew because I need MySQL command line (mainly for import and export).

Now entering mysql results in:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

What should I do?

Comment: Can YOu show you MySql Connection?... are you using PDO or MySqli??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The MAMP mysql socket is located elsewhere. If you installed MAMP and own mysql parallel, you have two instances.
One with MAMP context, which has its binary in

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/
```

Other one depending on your settings during install.

Make sure to start mysql (the one you would like to work with).
You might want to use command line as follows:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql [command goes here]
```

To access the MAMP mysql server.

Comment: For BitNami MAMPStack, I found MySQL here: `/Applications/mampstack-5.4.17-0/mysql/bin/mysql`